# Simple jQuery current selection function?

Tags: jquery, class

I have a few lists, and when a user clicks on an item I would like it to change the class to current, but if a users then clicks on another item in the same list to switch that to current and remove the current from the previous item selected.

any quick examples, i know this is probably out there already but couldn't find a good example.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

So if you click on item 1 it will be class current, but switch off if you click on item 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('ul#list li').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

references

- [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

## [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CevKU/)

---

It would be easy if you use the `li` in adding/removing `current` because of the siblings. But if you wan't to use the anchors, do it this way,

```
$('ul#list li a').click(function(){
   var li = $(this).parent();
   li.find('a').addClass('current');
   li.siblings().find('a').removeClass('current');
   return false;
});
```

or if you just want to use anchors just for the click event and still add/remove `current` on `li`, do this,

```
$('ul#list li a').click(function(){
   var li = $(this).parent();
   li.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it would not remove the class="current" from an anchor in the list.  I had to change it to:
$('ul#list li a').click(function(){
and it is adding the class but not removing it??

Comment: This worked very well.  My question is, applying that function to multiple <ul> on the same page doesn't work, but I feel as though it should since:
var li = $(this).parent();
should target the just the anchors in ul#list li and not ul#list2 li
or am I totally wrong in assuming that?

Comment: `var li = $(this).parent(); should target the just the anchors in ul#list li and not ul#list2 li` - you're correct.